# Where are the Visual Studio 2013 keybindings kept

Tags: visual-studio-2013

They should be in currentsettings.vssettings and if I do an export settings they should be in the exported file but all I see in the vssettings file to with the keyboard is this -

```
<KeyboardShortcuts Version="8.0">
    <ShortcutsScheme>Visual C++ 6</ShortcutsScheme>
</KeyboardShortcuts>
```

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is it because I happened to start with the VC6 settings that it's decided not to store them here? They're certainly stored somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the links provided by Google to see if you looked in the right place?

> By default, your shortcuts are saved in a file in the %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings folder. The name of the file reflects the date when you exported the settings, and the extension is .vssettings.

That was quoted from the article (referenced below), which also teaches you how to export keyboard shortcuts under "Sharing Custom Keyboard Shortcuts"

Reference link: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx)

**Here's what I have in my VSSettings** that are related to shortcuts:

```
<KeyboardShortcuts>
            <DefaultShortcuts/>
            <ScopeDefinitions>
                <Scope Name="VC Dialog Editor" ID="{543E0C02-8C85-4E43-933A-5EF320E3431F}"/>
                <Scope Name="UML Class Diagram" ID="{FE170F05-DE3A-4067-A3ED-08AE56B31DB3}"/>
                <Scope Name="Data Generator" ID="{D3936010-2B3A-4B8E-82D1-F4DCE3B5F898}"/>
                <!--Other shortcuts -->
            </ScopeDefinitions>
            <ShortcutsScheme/>
            <UserShortcuts/>
        </KeyboardShortcuts>
```

Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks, the shortcuts are now appearing in the settings file. I still have the settings export file from when I asked the question and they didn't appear in that file though they clearly existed and I exported all settings.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, assuming you selected all the same settings as well. Either way, if this answer has solved the issue do mark it as an answer!